# Neo4j Dijkstra's algorithm not returning / crashing

Tags: neo4j, dijkstra

Right now I am building a new routing engine. It exists of about 500 vertices and 30.000 edges. I've put these routes and airports in Neo4j and I've specified a distance attribute for every route (distance in KM between the two nodes).

However when I ask the simple question using the [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-graph-algos.html#rest-api-execute-a-dijkstra-algorithm-and-get-multiple-paths) implemented in Neo4j; it basically just crashes. Memory usage increases to 4GB and CPU usage increases to 150% (even when I give a max depth of 1).

My intuition says, this is because I have some cycles in my graph. If you imagine these routes between airports:

A > B > C

There might also exist a route:

C > A

So I think it keeps going back and forward between those C > A and then going back.

Is there a way, to stop Neo4J from going up in the "tree"? So basically saying, "Hey, I've already been there, no need to go back". My knowledge of Neo4j is limited so maybe it is something very simple.

Comment: Can you share your database? And the exact call you ran? Which Neo4j version did you use?

Comment: You want to go from A -> C ? Neo4j uses a bi-directional algorithm, so it extends from both sides. And you should of course specify the direction. It will not revisit the same path again and should also not walk in cycles.